# Implement a non-generic, static Factory method to create various Generic Classes from string input (without using "dynamic" type)

Tags: c#, factory, builder, strong-typing

I have a set of classes which are defined and populated from parsed XML.

As part of this, I want to be able to dynamically instantiate collection classes for particular types, as specified by the XML (in this case, to manage / instantiate exceptions).

So I have a class, approximately defined as follows:

```
public class ExceptionGroup<T> : BaseCollectionClass<Exception> where T : Exception 
{
    // contents of this class don't really matter
}
```

When I process the XML, I will have the name of the Exception-derived type contained in a string (i.e. "ArgumentNullException", "InvalidDataException", "IndexOutOfRangeException" etc.), as well as the content (message) that will be used to populate the generated Exception (also a string) when/if it's thrown.

So, to get where I'm trying to go, I first have implemented a couple of relevant static classes (defined elsewhere):

```
// Recursively determines if a supplied Type is ultimately derived from the Exception class:
public static bool IsException( Type type ) =>
    (type == typeof( object )) ? false : (type == typeof(Exception)) || IsException( type.BaseType );

// Figures out if the specified string contains the name of a recognized Type 
// and that the Type itself is genuinely derived from the Exception base class:
public static Type DeriveType( string name )
{
    // If the string is null, empty, whitespace, or malformed, it's not valid and we ignore it...
    if ( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( name ) && Regex.IsMatch( name, @"^([a-z][\w]*[a-z0-9])$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ) )
        try
        {
            Type excType = System.Type.GetType( name );
            if ( IsException( excType ) ) return excType;
        }
        catch { }

    // The type could not be determined, return null:
    return null; 
}
```

Using these classes, I can take an input string and end up with a known, existing, C# Type class (presuming the input string is valid) that's derived from the Exception class. Now I want to build a factory method that can create new `ExceptionGroup<T>` objects where "T" is the object type that's derived from the orignal string.

I've *kind of* managed this by using the `dynamic` type as the factory's return type as follows:

```
public static dynamic CreateExceptionGroup( string exceptionTypeName )
{
    Type excType = DeriveType( exceptionTypeName );
    if ( !(excType is null) )
    {
        Type groupType = typeof( ExceptionGroup<> ).MakeGenericType( new Type[] { excType } );
        return Activator.CreateInstance( groupType );
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm quite uncomfortable with this though, both because I dislike the ambiguity / uncertainty of the result, and because subsequently working with that result can be more cumbersome/complex. I'd much rather actually *specify* the return type more concretely, and then appropriately cast/qualify it in some manner, for example (yes, I *know* that this isn't valid!):

```
public static ExceptionGroup<> CreateGroup( string exceptionTypeName )
{
    Type excType = DeriveType( exceptionTypeName );
    if ( !(excType is null) )
    {
        Type[] types = new Type[] { excType };
        Type groupType = typeof( ExceptionGroup<> ).MakeGenericType( types );
        return (ExceptionGroup<>)Activator.CreateInstance( groupType );
    }
    return null;
}
```

...but, of course `ExceptionGroup<>` isn't valid in this syntax/context. (Generates "CS7003: Unexpected use of an unbound generic name"), and neither is merely using `ExceptionGroup` (Generates: "CS0305: Using the generic type 'ExceptionGroup' requires 1 type arguments.")

So, *IS* there a way to do this with strong(er) typing, via some other syntax or mechanism, with more precisely described results, or is using `dynamic`, with all of the subsequent associated overhead, literally the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why can't `CreateGroup` be generic? Do you not know what kind of exception group you are getting when you call `CreateGroup`? If you do know, you can specify the type of exception you want as a generic parameter. If you don't know, there are two cases. Either this can't be type safe, or it can be, but you will always get a `ExceptionGroup<Exception>` (since you don't know anything more than that at compile time). Which case it is depends on the contents of `ExceptionGroup`.

Comment: As the example code shows, when ```CreateGroup``` is called, all I have is a string of unknown content. I don't even have a populated TYPE class, let alone be somehow able to specify a generic in the calling code...
For some reason, C# is able to understand this need/formulation in the ```Type groupType = typeof( ExceptionGroup<> )``` context, but not in the function return-type context.

Comment: Then tell me, how on earth is the compiler going to know which specific type of `ExceptionGroup`  `CreateGroup` returns, and typecheck the subsequent expressions for you? You are at most getting the interface of an `ExceptionGroup<Exception>` at compile time, assuming the members of `ExceptionGroup` can be made into a covariant interface.

Comment: Uh, the same ways, presumably that it manages to do in the valid ```Type groupType = typeof( ExceptionGroup<> )``` declaration, and/or the same way(s) that it manages to make the correct deductions in Generic Type ```where``` declarations (i.e. ```... where T : Class``` when the compiler is clearly able to deduce that "Class" (in this context) includes not only "Class" itself, but all Class-derived types too).

Comment: Okay I understand what you are saying, but the compiler doesn't do that automatically. You need to declare a covariant interface to do that. Whether you are able to declare a covariant interface for all members of `ExceptionGroup`, depends on its contents. Please show the contents of `ExceptionGroup`. Just the signatures are enough, no need for the implementations.

Comment: Heh -- in answering your prior question, and thinking inheritance through, a solution actually occurred to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226183/discussion-between-netxpert-and-sweeper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I hope that there may be a more simple/ succinct solution (and would love to see it if so!) some retrospective prompting by Sweeper led me to the realisation that I could essentially bypass the problem by injecting the overhead of a new abstract ancestor class:

```
public abstract class ExceptionGroupFoundation : BaseCollectionClass<Exception>
{
    public ExceptionGroupFoundation( object[] args = null ) : base( args ) { }

    // Implement necessary common accessors, methods, fields, properties etc here...
    // (preferably "abstract" as/when/where possible)
}
```

... then deriving my generic class from *that* one:

```
public class ExceptionGroup<T> : ExceptionGroupFoundation where T : Exception 
{
    public ExceptionGroup( object[] args = null ) : base( args ) { }

    // contents of this class don't really matter
}
```

... then declaring my factory method using the new abstract class as the return type:

```
public static ExceptionGroupFoundation CreateGroup( string exceptionTypeName )
{
    Type excType = DeriveType( exceptionTypeName );
    if ( !(excType is null) )
    {
        Type[] types = new Type[] { excType };
        Type groupType = typeof( ExceptionGroup<> ).MakeGenericType( types );
        return (ExceptionGroupFoundation)Activator.CreateInstance( groupType );
    }
    return null;
}
```

...to essentially arrive at the desired result, albeit somewhat cumbersomely/awkwardly.